# Attaching a disconnected object to an NHibernate session; best practice?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My repository works in a `UnitOfWork` model; all operations, whether retrieval or persistence, must be performed within the scope of an `IDisposable` `UnitOfWork` token object, which behind the scenes is associated with a `Session` that performs the work requested. So, the basic pattern is:

```
using (var uow = repo.BeginUnitOfWork())
{
   try
   {
      //DB operations here; all repo methods require passing in uow.
      ...
      repo.CommitUnitOfWork(uow);
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      repo.RollbackUnitOfWork(uow);
      throw;
   }
}
```

I've also implemented some wrapper methods that allow you to specify a lambda or delegate that will be executed in this framework, relieving the need to implement all this scaffolding every time.

The problem I'm having is that using this model, code must "know" what the user needs, and eager-load it using `NHUtil.Initialize()` within the `UnitOfWork`. Once the UOW is disposed at the end of the using block, the Session associated with any `PersistentBags` is closed, and so they cannot be evaluated. As eager-loading everything up front is not always feasible and kind of defeats the purpose of a lazy-loading ORM, I am implementing an `Attach()` method.

Here's the question; In the absence of a built-in `ISession.Attach()` method, there are three methods I've seen recommended to associate an object with a new Session. Which of them is the best practice to get the job done?

A:

```
if(!Session.Contains(domainObject))
    Session.Update(domainObject);
```

B:

```
Session.Merge(domainObject);
```

C:

```
Session.Lock(domainObject, LockMode.None);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

D: None of the above. Effectively disabling lazy-loading by keeping your UOW too short and defeats the purpose of a lazy-loading ORM. The fact that you have to re-associate disconnected objects as normal operations means that your unit of work boundaries are wrong.

Merge, Update, and Lock all have different purposes. If you're stuck with your current architecture then Lock is probably what you want.

- Update - associates a changed object
- Lock - associates an unchanged object
- Merge - if the object exists in the
  current session then it is updated
  with changes from the merged object,
  otherwise it's the same as Lock

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not stuck with the current repo architecture. The basic pattern is that the UnitOfWork object is a flyweight token that implements IDisposable, calling back to the repo when disposed so the session is cleaned up. Currently, Dispose() MUST be called by user code, or else the DB is left open, so the using pattern has been most logical. the IDisposable implementation can be made more robust so it is invoked if necessary when the object is GCed, or I can look at some other pattern. Your suggestions?

Comment: Actually, cancel the "making more robust" part; there's a reference to the UOW in the repo, so unless explicitly disposed it won't be until the repo is disposed (and it stays in memory via an IoC container for the life of the program).

Comment: You should pass your UOW into the repository constructor. Personally I use the ISession directly instead of wrapping it. Disposing the ISession is important but in many cases it's impractical to wrap it in a using block and you have to call Dispose at the appropriate time.

Comment: To add to Jamie's answer, I think this is really the reason the Unit of Work-per-request approach is so widely used (if you're working on a web app).  Basically, you implement an IHttpModule which opens your UOW on application_BeginRequest, then on application_EndRequest you Commit your changes (or RollBack the UOW if there's an error), then dispose it as appropriate.
This way, the session/UOW handling should completely encapsulate your user code and you shouldn't have to worry about running into uninitialized proxies, etc.

Comment: +1 for pointing out UoW boundaries.  Made me think.  Mine were wrong. Ta.