# Does NHibernate have in-memory entities for updates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate. We are using Dapper for retrieval and planning to use NHibernate for CRUD.

I am trying to remove the child object through parent list object in one to many relationship.

This works when I retrieve the object using NHibernate session and remove the item.

```
var mercedes = Read("chevrolet"); //queries from nhibernate session
var model = mercedes.Models.Where(c => c.Id == 181).Single(); 
mercedes.Models.Remove(model);
```

When I manually create the object and attach thecars  models, it is unable to remove it.

```
var mercedes = new Make() { Id = 77, Name = "chevrolet" };//manually created the object
mercedes.Models = GetAllModels(77);//I have it in-memory            
var model = mercedes.Models.Where(c => c.Id == 173).Single();
mercedes.Models.Remove(model);
```

I think I am doing something weird. But I am able to add/update the models using second approach, so why can't i remove it. Any insights please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new domain object it isn't attached to the NHibernate session (unless you are creating a new object and call Save, for instance).  As such, deleting from the models collection doesn't actually do anything.

Your second example doesn't seem like a particularly good practice  but you *can* [recreate an object and attach it to your NHibernate session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444753/486620)  using `Session.Lock` (`Merge` or `Update` are fairly normal depending on your preferred behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes without attaching session doesn't seem to work.