# NHibernate lazy collection wasn't loaded

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have couple of classes whrapped via NHibernate and underlying DB. Fir exmaple, call classes following way:

```
class Parent {
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

class Child {
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Of course I have mappign and it is working fine in ASP.NET application. now I want to intoduce unit test and faced strange error: in test setup method some test data created (i.e. `Parent`) and its `Id` stored in test class. In test method I asking my repo to get my entity by this `Id` and it returns NNibernate proxy object (if I remember right something called `Bag`). When I trying to access my colelction of children I have got and exception `NHibernate.LazyInitializationException : Initializing failed to lazily initialize a collection of role`

I read similr questions  here but all of them recomment "just do not close session". I cannot do it. Is there any way to retrieve this collection on test data creation to have access to it in future?

Comment: Well, you can do it. in your setup method, or even before... open the session. On Test Cleanup... close, dispose it...

Comment: @RadimKöhler this is not the case. I do not want to change default behavior of session manager.

Comment: Well, the `SessionManager`, should manage the sessions for you. We should not be slaves of it, I'd say. Unit tests, in my view, should be in this scenario provided with ONE open session, lasting from the test init to the test cleanup. That's how I am working with NHiberante and Unit tests for many years. But take it as a suggestion, just my view ... ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler I understand your approach but not sure I can agree with you. In our development process we are using following way: test fixture creates test data which stored in unit tests DB? after that each unit test in class can operate with this data but at the same time each unit test rollback transaction at the end. This way we can guarantee that test data will be untouched and not thrash appears in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using this test pattern, your only options are to re-attach the object created in the setup to the session in the test method.

I'd suggest using `Session.Lock(object, LockMode.None)` but see this question and answer for more details: [Attaching a disconnected object to an NHibernate session; best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444559/attaching-a-disconnected-object-to-an-nhibernate-session-best-practice)